# Calculate Distance and time between two way points - Leaflet Routing Machine

Tags: routes, maps, leaflet, directions

As per the instruction from this site http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/, I can able to generate route between waypoints.

However, I need to get distance and time to travel between two stops provided.

Is it possible to achieve this with leaflet routing machine? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Skip leaflet-routing-machine altogether and query one of the routing backends (OSRM, graphhopper, mapbox directions, mapzen valhalla, etc).

For example, [MapZen Valhalla](https://mapzen.com/documentation/turn-by-turn/api-reference/#outputs-of-a-route) will give you both time and distance of a route as default.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two stops allowed, you can always create three routes that are transparent to the user's eyes:

1. A route between the starting point and the first stop.
2. A route between the first stop and the second stop.
3. A route between the second stop and the arrival point.

This way you get the total time and distances for each leg of the route.